# Typescript Injecting Generic Array into component

Tags: angular, generics, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm currently trying and failing in Angular 4 to inject an object into a component that extends a generic `Array<T>` at the moment with the following I'm getting a 'function test() is undefined' at the console. Is there any extra decorators etc. that I'm currently missing in the constructor of the component or should this work? Removing the extends Array works.

```
@Injectable()
export class MySourceList extends Array<Source> {


  constructor (

  ) {
    super();
  }



  test(){
    alert('test');
  }

}
```

component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'mysource-list',
  templateUrl: './mysource-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mysource-list.component.css'],
  providers: [MySourceList]
})
  constructor(
     private sourceList:MySourceList
  ) {

      sourceList.test();
  }
```

Comment: This is not Angular question. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work